# Ubuntu 14.04 isn't detecting my USB headset

Tags: sound, 14.04

I'm having problems getting Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 to detect my G35 Logitech Headset. I've tried to plug it in and go to System_Settings/Sound but the device is not appearing in the output nor the input tab.

My speakers do appear and are working perfectly fine. Analog headphones are working as well.

lsusb prints:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0738:1708 Mad Catz, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:0a15 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1ea7:2001  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! Please help us help you by providing the output of `lsusb` to your question! Thank you!

Comment: @ElderGeek Done! I'm new with Linux so please forgive my noobness :)

Comment: Thank you! Can you try it in a different USB port? Here's a good troubleshooting guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Comment: Any progress????

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. Turned out the headphones weren't plugged in correctly :D

However:

1. Try `lsusb` with and without headset plugged in to see whether there's a difference (for me `Bus 001 Device 009: ID 046d:0a45 Logitech, Inc.` appeared)
2. Try installing `pavucontrol`, at least I have it installed, since I was fixing some Skype issues.

Good luck